# When to use Bots, FaaS, Runbooks and logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, runbook, azure-bot-service

All these Azure technologies (Bots, FaaS, Logic Apps and Runbooks) are used to run schadule jobs.

I don't know when we should use these and which scenario we should use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YMMV, but here are some pretty good rule of thumbs:

1. Are you doing PowerShell based Automation work? If Yes, consider Azure Automation Runbooks.
2. Are you building a bot? If Yes, consider the Azure Bot Framework service.
3. Are you build a workflow that executes on a timer, especially one that integrates with other services (etc.)? If Yes, consider Logic Apps.
4. Are you writing generic application code? If Yes, consider Azure Functions.

If none of those fit, I'd be surprised, but you might try starting with Azure Functions since we're kind of an "Everything as a Service", but there is a reason we have the different products - they specialize to enable better productivity within their specialty (Bots, Automation, and Integration).

Note: I'm one of the PMs on the Azure Functions team here at Microsoft.

Comment: Where is Azure WebJobs located?

Comment: If you're in the Functions bucket but Functions itself won't work for some reason, WebJobs SDK or App Service Web App WebJobs (say that 10 times fast) would be the next logical thing to evaluate.